# ASP.NET 5 developing on Windows but running on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, windows

Since ASP.NET 5 can run on both Windows and Linux :

1. Is it possible to develop on Windows and then deploy on a Linux machine?
2. Does the "publish" in visual studio for MVC project still work in that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, so long as you don't do anything platform specific (ex: Linux has no Registry) and you develop for .NET Core
2. It depends on what type of publish. But even then, you don't have to limit yourself to what VS can do. You can write your own publish scripts if you want.

Comment: By publish script you mean running a script on the linux server that will pull the latest version from our git repository, compile it and then run it?

Comment: @Gudradain That's one possibility. With scripting, you can do anything. You could have a PowerShell script that you run on your PC that pushes code to your Linux server. You can have a BASH script on the Linux server that pulls the code from your PC or source code control. Or you can have Continue Integration set up so that a build server handles deployments when it detects an updated branch. It's all about how you want it to work. That's called Dev Ops.